# Does higher convergence order guarantee higher convergence speed?

Tags: numerical-methods, convergence-divergence

We say that the sequence converges with order $q$ to $L$ for $q>1$ if
$$ \lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{|x_{k+1}-L|}{|x_k-L|^q} = \mu, \quad\; \mu > 0.$$

If $a_k$ converges with order $p$, $b_k$ converges with order $q$ 
and $p<q$, can we prove $b_k$ converges faster than $a_k$?

By converging faster I mean
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{|b_k-L|}{|a_k-L|}=0
$$

If it was the same sequence, I can prove convergence with order $q$ implies convergence with order $p$. However, here are two sequences and I don't know how to prove it.

Does higher convergence order guarantee higher convergence speed? Thank you.